# Extracting value from object using utility function

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to simplify null-safe value extraction. I want to make the code easy to read and maintain. I don't want to use an `Optional<T>` because of the cost to instantiate the object and other utilities therein. I am inclined to create a utility function `get(S object, Function<S, T> mapper)` as such

```
public static <S, T> T get(S object, Function<S, T> mapper) {
    if(object == null || mapper == null) {
        return null;
    }
    
    return mapper.apply(object);
}
```

However, I fear the `mapper` would again incur a object instantiation cost, or would it? Is it much more expensive than the traditional tertiary operator?

```
object == null ? null : object.getValue();
```

**My question is:** Is the `Function<,> mapper` cheaper than `Optional<>`

Comment: This sounds like the kind of question to which the first answer is "why not run it, and time it?" because it sounds like you're trying to microoptimize, which means you shouldn't be taking folks at their word anyway. You should _test_ and see what each thing actually does when you run it in practice. Including using `Optional<T>`, of course. Test all of them, write down the results, then look at which are acceptable to you.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the way I've worded it does sound like that. My intention was more to findout if there could be a difference between instantiating a Function vs Optional. Of course, I could test it to get the stats but I am trying to understand the theory behind it. What are the factors that affect object initialization cost.

Comment: Its up to you - if you can manage to make `mapper` a singleton, no extra object would be created.